# Spring Security "<authorize url='...'>" tag failed to evaluate url properly when there are multiple <http> elements

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to use spring security's "url" attribute of `<authorize>` tag. I got into a weird situation where the tag seems doesn't take effect.

My business need is to use two `<http>` elements, one for web service access and another for normal user access: the web service access is stateless but the user access is session based, that is why we need two http elements.

To illustrate this problem, I will use the spring security 3.1.4 tutorial instead. I can reproduce this problem by only adding one extra `<http>` element to the spring config file.

The original applicationContext-secutiry.xml from tutorial is defined like this:

```
<http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/loggedout.jsp" security="none"/>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/extreme/**" access="hasRole('supervisor')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    ....
 </http>
```

It's landing page, index.jsp, uses "authorize" tag like this:

```
<sec:authorize url='/secure/index.jsp'>
<p>
    You can currently access "/secure" URLs.
</p>
</sec:authorize>
```

When a user first time tries to access this page, the tag will check the permission to url '/secure/index.jsp', which requires authentication and thus, the tag will NOT displace its content and UI display message like.

Your principal object is....: null

Now, change applicationContext-security.xml by adding a new http element before the last "http" element

```
<http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/loggedout.jsp" security="none"/>

<!--This is the new element added-->
<http pattern="/user/**"
     use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('user')"/>
    <http-basic />
 </http>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/extreme/**" access="hasRole('supervisor')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    ....
 </http>
```

Now, I access the index.jsp (no login yet) and the page actually prints out a message saying:

Your principal object is....: null
You can currently access "/secure" URLs.
You can currently access "/secure/extreme" URLs.

The "authorize" tag evaluates to true in this case, even if I haven't logged in!

I tried to debug through source code, DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource, and found that when the first http request, "/index.jsp" comes in, it uses the default  element (the last one) in applicationContext-security.xml but when the "" tag tries to check access to "/secure/index.jsp", DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource is using the new  element and its getAttributes() return null to DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator which eventually return true.

This looks like a spring security bug to me: the authorize tag url, "/secure/index.jsp" should match the default "http", not the other one.

One workaround I used is to copy the "intercept-url" definitions for "/secure/index.jsp" and "/secure/extreme/index.jsp" from the default "http" to the new "http" element and then the UI works as expected. But I don't want to copy codes!

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I did some further debugging of spring security source. I found that two DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator were created, one for the third <http> and one for the last (default). The JSP tag always uses the first evaluator found. Any reason why Spring Security does that and How to fix it? Write my own custom tag?

Comment: Turns out there is a way to overwrite this capability in spring security 3.1.3. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2045

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue as following.

Java:

```
package com.github.kazuki43zoo.web.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluatorProvideFilter implements Filter,
        WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator, BeanPostProcessor {

    private List<WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator> webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluators = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setAttribute(WebAttributes.WEB_INVOCATION_PRIVILEGE_EVALUATOR_ATTRIBUTE, this);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluators.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAllowed(String uri, Authentication authentication) {
        for (WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator privilegeEvaluator : webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluators) {
            if (!privilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(uri, authentication)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAllowed(String contextPath, String uri, String method,
            Authentication authentication) {
        for (WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator privilegeEvaluator : webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluators) {
            if (!privilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(contextPath, uri, method, authentication)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator
                && !bean.getClass().isAssignableFrom(getClass())) {
            webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluators.add((WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator) bean);
        }
        return bean;
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CustomWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluatorProvideFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>customWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluatorProvideFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CustomWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluatorProvideFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, code-only answers are generally not sufficient. Please explain exactly what your code does to solve the problem in the original post, and why this solution is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext ctx = org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
java.util.Map<String, org.springframework.security.web.access.WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator>
        wipes = ctx.getBeansOfType(org.springframework.security.web.access.WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.class);

if(wipes.size() > 0){
    //I need last one
    org.springframework.security.web.access.WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator appEvaluator =
            (WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator)wipes.values().toArray()[wipes.size() - 1];

    //set request attribute so that JSP tag can use it        request.setAttribute(org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes.WEB_INVOCATION_PRIVILEGE_EVALUATOR_ATTRIBUTE
            , appEvaluator);

}
```